# Qual a origem de "a água corrente não mata a gente"?

Tags: expressões, expressões-idiomáticas, frases

Qual a origem da expressão "A água corrente não mata a gente"?

É de Portugal ou Brasil?

Comment: Sabes se é usada em algum dos dois países? Procuraste? Encontraste usos nos dois países?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem versões desse provérbio em várias línguas. Em italiano já existia em 1612:

> L’acqua che corre, non porta veleno [A água que corre não traz veneno]
>   [*Vocabolario degli Accademici della Crusca*, Veneza, 1612](https://books.google.pt/books?id=W71KAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PP9&dq=%22Acqua%20che%20corre%20non%20porta%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTlYjU0aLpAhURmxQKHRWGBAY4FBDoAQjEATAP#v=onepage&q=%22Acqua%20che%20corre%20non%20porta%22&f=false)

Segundo *Le Livre de Proverbes Français* já existia no século XV em francês:

> Esve (*eau*) que court ne porte point d’ordures [Água que corre não traz imundícies]
>   [*Le Livre des Proverbes Français*, Paris, 1842](https://books.google.pt/books?id=egsJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA42&dq=%22eau%20qui%20court%20ne%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjynsvL06LpAhUQAGMBHbXfC9gQ6AEIXzAG#v=onepage&q=%22eau%20qui%20court%20ne%22&f=false)

Em espanhol temos o mesmo que em português — “Agua corriente no mata gente” — registado em 1900 neste [*La Argentina* de H. Damián](http://Hhttps://books.google.pt/books?id=E-IdAAAAMAAJ&q=%22agua%20corriente%20no%20mata%20gente%22&dq=%22agua%20corriente%20no%20mata%20gente%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw1vL4zKLpAhU3D2MBHZK7Arg4FBDoAQg3MAI).

Em português, o mais antigo que encontrei foi em 1882, mas já então era considerado um velho rifão:

> Ha um velho rifão que diz — **agua corrente não mata**. Esta sentença conhecida e sabida de todos, é santificada pela sciencia.
>   [*Commercio de Portugal*, Lisboa, 17-11-1882](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=890375&pesq=%22agua%20corrente%20n%C3%A3o%20mata%20esta%22&pasta=ano%20188)

A versão longa só encontrei em 1931:

> […] o adágio: *água corrente não mata gente*, tirado de justa observação da Natureza.
>   *Revista Lusitana*, v. 28,  Lisboa, 1931, p. 179 (disponível na [Biblioteca Digital Camões](http://bibliotecasicl.pt/Opac/Pages/Search/Results.aspx?SearchText=Revista%20Lusitana&DataBase=105199_GLOBAL&Operator=AND&Profile=Default))

Estes exemplos em português sugerem que a mensagem deste provérbio teve a sua origem na “justa observação da Natureza”, depois “santificada pela sciencia”. No campo, especialmente em tempos passados, livres de pesticidas e adubos químicos, as águas correntes dos ribeiros eram razoavelmente seguras; as paradas eram mais propícias ao desenvolvimento de germes e acumulação de porcaria. Eu cresci numa comunidade agrícola, nunca ouvi este provérbio, mas o meu pai dizia-me para beber de águas correntes, mas não das paradas.

Em publicações brasileiras, só encontrei o provérbio em 1948 [(Cid Cercal, *Troças e trocas*)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=I3oVAQAAMAAJ&q=%22%C3%A1gua%20corrente%20n%C3%A3o%20mata%22&dq=%22%C3%A1gua%20corrente%20n%C3%A3o%20mata%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiana28xKLpAhXR8eAKHfDdCPMQ6AEIzgEwEg). Mas também encontrei lá em 1900 a ideia que a água corrente “sanifica” enquanto a “empantanada” “apodrece e empesta”  ([*A Imprensa*, Rio de Janeiro, 1900](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=245038&pesq=%22agua%20corrente%20agua%22&pasta=ano%20190)) e que “pela agua corrente não póde chegar ao intimo do organismo a larva do parasita” ([*Brazil-Medico*, Rio de Janeiro, 1904](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=081272&pesq=%22agua%20corrente%20n%C3%A3o%22&pasta=ano%20190)).

Os provérbios são uma forma de expressão da sabedoria popular e podem ser transmitidos oralmente durante séculos antes de serem escritos (especialmente, em algo que eu consiga encontrar na internet). Que as águas correntes é que são boas para beber deve ser coisa que todos os povos antigos sabiam. Dada a antiguidade das versões italiana francesa, não me surpreenderia nada que este ditado ou versão equivalente existisse em Portugal já na Idade Média e que tivesse sido levado pelos primeiros colonos para o Brasil. E também me surpreenderia nada que os nessa altura os índios tivessem também as suas versões.

Comment: Resposta muito completa e interessante.